# NumberFormatException when inserting into OrientDB table

Tags: javascript, node.js, orientdb, oriento

I'm using oriento to insert into my OrientDB database:

```
db.insert().into('User').set(user).one()
.then (user) =>
    created()
.error (e) =>
    error "Error creating user #{ user["objectId"] }", {user:user, error:e}
```

And after 1868 rows, I got this error output (first the erroneous user object, then the error object):

> Error creating user T6bALDD7vf
>   {"user":{"settings":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Settings","objectId":"L89RW0E7pB"},"acceptedTerms":true,"activitiesCount":1,"appFirstUseDate":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2014-03-21T09:46:14.669Z"},"bio":".","birthday":{"__type":"Date","iso":"1992-06-10T00:00:00.000Z"},"email":"REMOVED@hotmail.com","equipment":{"1":[6,100,105,107,4]},"followerCount":0,"followingCount":0,"gender":2,"goal":1,"height_unit":2,"height_val1":1,"height_val2":64,"kitchenSinkBadgesSeen":["activity","schedule","findfriends","log","share","workouts/today"],"lastVersionUsed":"2.4.2","level":2,"location":"Azerbaijan","numReferrals":0,"platform":2,"popularFeedLastReadAt":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2014-04-09T10:56:10.054Z"},"postCount":1,"seenHamburgerInstructions":true,"stream":"b","timezone":"Asia/Baku","unsubscribedFromWorkoutEmails":true,"username":"gulnara","website":"google.com","weight":62,"weight_unit":2,"createdAt":"2014-03-21T09:48:34.152Z","updatedAt":"2014-04-09T10:57:24.883Z","objectId":"T6bALDD7vf","ACL":{"*":{"read":true},"T6bALDD7vf":{"read":true,"write":true}},"sessionToken":"jgaq50y07p07053h5f0x9gkt6"},"error":{"name":"OrientDB.RequestError","message":null,"data":{},"previous":[{"name":"OrientDB.RequestError","data":{}}],"id":1,"type":"java.lang.NumberFormatException","hasMore":0}}
>   [0.013s]

Any idea what it's referring to?

Here's the output from my `server.sh`:

```
-> java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:498)
-> java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:383)
-> java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:806)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.string.ORecordSerializerStringAbstract.getTypeValue(ORecordSerializerStringAbstract.java:469)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequestTextAbstract.fromStream(OCommandRequestTextAbstract.java:149)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequestTextAbstract.fromStream(OCommandRequestTextAbstract.java:73)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.stream.OStreamSerializerAnyStreamable.fromStream(OStreamSerializerAnyStreamable.java:73)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.command(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:1152)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.executeRequest(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:340)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.execute(OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.java:169)
-> com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:45)
```

Comment: Sounds like a field is missing/set to undefined or NaN in one of the the users headed in. That will give a 'undefined' or 'NaN' value to Java who says "oh no, its NaN, but NaN = atomic explosion since I'm Java"

Comment: Can you find what's the field responsible to give you that exception?

Comment: How can I find the responsible field? I've looked through that object many times and everything looks normal. Is there a log somewhere with more detailed data on the error?